# How to change the color of TOC part font using tocloft

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, color, tocloft

I have customised my toc using `tocloft` for everything from `chapter` down to `subsection`, but I cant work out how to change the color of the part font, how do you renew this command? I have read the `tocloft` documentation and can't find anything. Thanks for any help!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twopage]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}
\newcommand{\partfont}{\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\color{RoyalRed}}}

\newenvironment{MainTOC}{\partfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{MainTOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{MainTOC}

\part{first part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\part{second part}
\chapter{second chapter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\cftpartfont` for changing the font of part title and its number and `cftpartpagefont` for changing the font for page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\color{olive}}
\renewcommand\cftpartpagefont{\color{olive}}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \part{A part}
  \chapter{a chapter}
  \part{another part}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I dont seem to be getting any errors but it isn't actually changing the color. I am redefining the command to use in an environment `\newcommand{\partfont}{\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\color{RoyalRed}}}`  and `\newenvironment{MainTOC}{\partfont`. I can't imagine this is the problem as it works for everything else, ill post a MWE in an edit

Comment: So it works in my MWE but not in my actual document, do you have any ideas why this may be?

Comment: @PaulBarr No idea. But `\newenvironment` should have two arguments like 

   `\newenvironment{MainTOC}{\partfont}{}`

Comment: No worries, Ill build it up again and see whats going wrong. Thanks, whats the second argument for?

Comment: @PaulBarr First one for starting code, and second one for ending.

Comment: I have been fiddling with the commands and `\cftpartfont` seems to be changing the page number color when I do the following: `\newcommand{\partfont}{\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\color{grey}}}`

Comment: as does changing \cftpartpagefont