# tocloft's part font color clashes with hyperref's linkcolor

Tags: hyperref, color, tocloft

```
%  tocloft's part font color clashes with hyperref's linkcolor

\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{book}

\usepackage[]{tocloft}

\usepackage{xcolor}
%  I'd like to change the tocloft's cftpartfont color using:
\newcommand{\partfont}{\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\color{olive}}}
% But it doesn't change because I'm using:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=true,         % if I comment this line out,
 linkcolor=red!80!black,  % the cftpartfont functions right
 urlcolor=green!50!black, % but in that case, for instance,
 hyperfootnotes=false,    % the footnotes' colorings become all black
 hypertexnames,           % which is undesirable
 bookmarks=true           % I'd like to use both hyperref's colorlinks
}                         % and tocloft's cftpartfont

% 5 suggestions I've tried to solve the tocloft - hyperref's colorlinks issue

% http://www.verycomputer.com/18_1efc8a75055d2fb4_1.htm (tocloft, tocbibind and hyperref together?)
% https://groups.google.com/g/comp.text.tex/c/Moj6kslHWVU (Combining Tocloft and hyperref)
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630002/hyperlinks-in-custom-list-of-via-tocloft
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239144/how-to-change-the-color-of-toc-part-font-using-tocloft
% https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=1SXK (suggests putting \tableofcontents into an environment like:
\newenvironment{MainTOC}{\partfont}{}

% None of the suggestions helped. I can't use those two options:
% tocloft's cftpartfont (assigning it a color) and hyperref's colorlinks=true
% How to use them together in this setup?

\begin{document}

\begin{MainTOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{MainTOC}

\part{first part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\part{second part}
\chapter{second chapter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new pdf management (with which hyperref uses an improved driver) which you load by using `\DocumentMetadata` at the begin of your document, you could disable colorlinks locally. Without the new driver you have to redefine an internal hyperref command.

Be aware that the options `bookmarks` and `hyperfootnotes` can't be set in `hypersetup`, they will be ignored there and must be set as package options.

`\DocumentMetadata` requires a current LaTeX

```
%\DocumentMetadata{} % uncomment to use the new pdfmanagement
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{book}

\usepackage[]{tocloft}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\disablelinkcolor{%
 %\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}% with \DocumentMetadata{}
 \def\HyColor@UseColor##1{}%
 }
\makeatother
\newcommand{\partfont}{\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\disablelinkcolor\color{olive}}}
% But it doesn't change because I'm using:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=true,         % if I comment this line out,
 linkcolor=red!80!black,  % the cftpartfont functions right
 urlcolor=green!50!black, % but in that case, for instance,
 hypertexnames,           % which is undesirable
}                         % and tocloft's cftpartfont


\newenvironment{MainTOC}{\partfont}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{MainTOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{MainTOC}

\part{first part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\label{blub}

\nameref{blub}
\part{second part}
\chapter{second chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked out the problem instantly. Actually I was thinking that it was a hard problem. Meanwhile, my version of TexLive is 2020.

Answer (score 2):

Be a bit more clever:

```
\colorlet{mylinkcolor}{red!80!black}
\newcommand{\partfont}{\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\colorlet{mylinkcolor}{olive}}}
 ...
\hypersetup{
 ...
 linkcolor=mylinkcolor,  
 ...
}
```

this works and is limited as the part entries are typeset inside a group.

Comment: That's a nice trick.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried it and it worked the problem out. I note it for its cleverness.