# Change only the color of the chapters link in the toc using hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, books, links

### My actual situation

I set (with the following commands) that in the table of contents each `chapter` element is represented with the color `steelblue`, while sections and subsections are represented in `black`.

```
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0cm]
{\addvspace{14pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
{\color{steelblue}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}{}
{\color{steelblue}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries
 \;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[0cm]
{\addvspace{6pt}\sffamily\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}{}
{\sffamily\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage}[]
```

[image]

The problem is that my toc does not create any links to the referenced pages.
Therefore, in order to generate a toc with the links, I thought to add the `hyperref` package

### The issue

After adding the package named above, I cannot determine how to color the chapters of the toc (`steelblue`) differently from all other components.
I have found a workaround, which I mark in the following code, but I am not satisfied with it as the clickable reference is only placed on the page number (and not on the `chapter/section/...` "tag")

```
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     
    bookmarksopen=true,         
    bookmarksopenlevel=3,   
    colorlinks, 
    breaklinks,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=black,
    linktocpage=true, 
}
```

[image]

### My goal

I am trying to figure out how to change **just** the color of the chapter links in the toc of my project.
Unfortunately, just putting `colorlinks=true` in the `hypersetup` everything becomes monochrome (which is red by default, but even changing it with `linkcolor` the issue is still the same).
[image]

#### MWE

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{mybook}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Chapters
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

`mybook.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mybook}
\LoadClass[11pt]{book}

% Colors
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{steelblue}{RGB}{70,130,180}

% Table of contents styling
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0cm]
{\addvspace{14pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
{\color{steelblue}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}{}
{\color{steelblue}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries
 \;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[0cm]
{\addvspace{6pt}\sffamily\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}{}
{\sffamily\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage}[]
```

Comment: Well either don't use colorlinks, and if you don't like the red borders to zero, or see daleif's answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655513/2388. That is basically the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\hypersetup{<options>}` as in [How to use different colors for different \href commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61015/how-to-use-different-colors-for-different-href-commands)

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0cm]
{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\color{green}\addvspace{14pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} %<!---- NEW BIT
{\hypersetup{linkcolor=steelblue}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}   %<!---- NEW BIT
{}
{\normalsize\sffamily\;\color{red}\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
```

The code below gives the following:

[image]

Here's a complete edited version of `mybook.cls`; I've marked the new bits.

### mybook.cls

```tex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mybook}
\LoadClass[11pt]{book}

% Colors
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{steelblue}{RGB}{70,130,180}

% Table of contents styling
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}   %<!-------- NEW BIT
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

%
% default hyperref settings
%
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=3,
    colorlinks,
    breaklinks,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=black,
    linktoc=all,  %<!--------- NEW BIT
}

%
% chapter
%
\titlecontents{chapter}[0cm]
{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\color{green}\addvspace{14pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} %<!---- NEW BIT
{\hypersetup{linkcolor=steelblue}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}   %<!---- NEW BIT
{}
{\normalsize\sffamily\;\color{red}\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

% 
% section
%
\titlecontents{section}[0cm]
{\hypersetup{linkcolor=yellow}\addvspace{6pt}\sffamily\bfseries}        %<!---- NEW BIT
{\hypersetup{linkcolor=orange}\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}%<!---- NEW BIT
{}
{\sffamily\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage}[]
```

Comment: That's almost perfect! Just a question: what if I want to keep the number before "Chapter X" the same color? I've tried many options so far, but think I'm still missing something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @LukeTheWolf see update :)